# SlateJs RenderMark in more than one plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I am using **renderMark** in multiple plugins, but only the top plugin in the plugin stack gets called, the remaining are ignored.

// first plugin

```
function MarkHotkey(options) {
  const { type, key, RenderTag, icon } = options

  return {
    onKeyDown(event, editor, next) {
      if (!event.ctrlKey || event.key != key) return next();
      event.preventDefault();
      editor.toggleMark(type)
    },
    renderMark(props, editor, next){
      const { children, mark, attributes } = props;
      if(type === mark.type){
       return <u {...attributes}>{children}</u>
     }
      next();
    }
```

// second plugin

```
function MarkHotkey1(options) {
  const { type, key, RenderTag, icon } = options
  return {
    onKeyDown(event, editor, next) {
      if (!event.ctrlKey || event.key != key) return next();
      event.preventDefault();
      editor.toggleMark(type)
    },
    renderMark(props, editor, next){
      const { children, mark, attributes } = props;
      if(type === mark.type){
       return <i {...attributes}>{children}</i>
      }
      next();
    }
```

// plugin array

```
const plugins = [
  MarkHotkey1({ key: 'i', type: 'italic' ,RenderTag : 'em',icon :''}),
  MarkHotkey({ key: 'u', type: 'underline' ,RenderTag : 'u',icon :''}),
]
```

// rendering editor with plugins

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: Value.fromJSON(initialValue), // editor initialisation
  }

  onChange = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }

  render() {
    return <Editor 
    value={this.state.value} 
    onChange={this.onChange}
    plugins={plugins}
    />
  }

}

export default App;
```

When I press **ctrl+i** it is working as expected, while **ctrl+u** is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *return* `next()`, not just call it. After that your plugins should fire in the sequence they're listed, and continue passing the events down until one of them doesn't *return* `next()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Happy to help! It was only obvious to me because I made it a bunch of times!